# Using divisibility and greatest common divisor for a proof

Tags: divisibility

If u|t and v|t and gcd(u,v)=1, then prove that (uv)|t

I started by analyzing the definition of divisibility and I got that (uv)|t^2, but this doesn't help me.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: Lemma: if $v\mid ab$ and $\gcd(v,b)=1$ then $v\mid a$. Application: $v\mid \frac{t}{u}u$ and $\gcd(v,u)=1\implies v\mid\frac{t}{u}$.

Comment: Nice work finding all these duplicates, @Goos!